# textView not updating android

Tags: android, textview, runnable, numberpicker

Hi I've been looking around and have got the following code.

It sort of works, onCreate the total TextField updates to the value it's meant to however after that nothing..

The onCreate bit

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                       total.setText(totalTimeToString());
                   }
            });
            }

    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

The totalTimeToString()

```
public String totalTimeToString(){
    String temp = convert(total());
    return temp;
}
```

the total() is simply getting the value of two number pickers and adding them together and the convert() method converts the total to HH:MM:SS string format.

Any help would be welcome. I am a complete newbie.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Why do you have a Runnable inside another one?

Comment: @nKn so when the application is launched the values of the number pickers are taken and the textview widget gets updated but after that if I try to change the value of the number picker from the UI the textview does not update. Thats the only issue at the moment.

(to matheusjardimB) I have no idea lul. I'm completely new to android dev and the version one to my app was the culmination of code from this very website :')

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chana.revisionTimer

Take a look if you like :)